# How to set primary ID when create new Object Model record in PrestaShop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I want check if ID reserved in DB, delete it and add new record with this ID.

```
$model = new TaxRulesGroup(2);
$model->delete();

$model->id = 2;
$model->id_tax_rules_group = 2;
$model->name = 'new name';
$model->active = 1;

$model->add();
```

any ideas ? Thank you.

Comment: Well, what's wrong with your code? do you get an error?

Comment: You can directly update, why need to delete it?

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre it's no errors. Because when I try this code in database I get new ID not old ID is keep with new record.

Comment: @TinkuRana It's for if not for example ID 2 in database create record with ID 2. It's need to our current task. Thank you. have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

From the ObjectModel class has attribute "force_id". I love PrestaShop. ;)

```
/** @var bool Enables to define an ID before adding object. */
public $force_id = false;
```